# object has no attribute, working with classes

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

keep getting 'RestaurantReview' object has no attribute '_RestaurantReview__name' but it seems as if I have passed everything into ReviewRestaurant from the Review class correctly

```
class Review:
    def __init__(self, nm, dt, strs):
        self.__name = nm
        self.__date = dt
        self.__stars = strs

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_date(self, date):
        self.__date = date
    def set_stars(self,stars):
        self.__stars = stars
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_date(self):
        return self.__date
    def get_stars(self):
        return self.__stars
    def __str__(self):
        return 'RESTAURANT: ' + 'Name: ' + str(self.__name) + 'Date: ' + str(self.__date) + 'Number of stars: ' + str(self.__stars)

class RestaurantReview:
    def __init__(self, nm, dt, strs, csne):
        Review.__init__(self, nm, dt, strs)
        self.__cuisine = csne
    def set_cuisine(self, cuisine):
        self.__cuisine = cuisine
    def get_cuisine(self):
        return self.__cuisine

    def __str__(self):
        return 'RESTAURANT: ' + 'Name: ' + str(self.__name) + 'Date: ' + str(self.__date) + 'Number of stars: ' + str(self.__stars) + 'Cuisine' + str(self.__cuisine)


def main():
    r2 = RestaurantReview('Red Robin', '5-3-18', 4, 'Burgers')
    print(r2)

main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: Use just one *underscore* to name your fields: `self._name`.

Comment: all fields are supposed to have two underscores and be private

Comment: `RestaurantReview` needs to be a subclass of `Review` for this to work.  And if you insist on making your fields private, then you need to call your getter methods rather than trying to use `self.__name` in a different class than where that field was created.

Comment: Double underscore doesn't mean private. Python != Java.  Is this an assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare RestaurantReview as a subclass of Review :

```
class Review:
    def __init__(self, nm, dt, strs):
        self.__name = nm
        self.__date = dt
        self.__stars = strs

    def __str__(self):
        return 'RESTAURANT: ' + 'Name: ' + str(self.name) + 'Date: ' + str(self.date) + 'Number of stars: ' + str(self.stars)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self.__date

    @property
    def stars(self):
        return self.__stars

class RestaurantReview(Review):
    def __init__(self, nm, dt, strs, csne):
        super(RestaurantReview, self).__init__(nm, dt, strs)
        self.__cuisine = csne

    @property
    def cuisine(self):
        return self.__cuisine

    def __str__(self):
        return 'RESTAURANT: ' + 'Name: ' + str(self.name) + 'Date: ' + str(self.date) + 'Number of stars: ' + str(self.stars) + 'Cuisine' + str(self.cuisine)


def main():
    r2 = RestaurantReview('Red Robin', '5-3-18', 4, 'Burgers')
    print(r2)

main()
```

You don't need to privatise your attributes, otherwise you have to create getter methods to access each of your private attributes.

EDIT : I left the attributes as private, and added properties to get their values.

Comment: this works but the attributes need to be private for what I'm trying to do, i did forget setters upon submitting this which i have edited, but it still does not work

Comment: I edited my answer so that your attributes are still private, but their values are accessible by the mean of properties.

Comment: The "double-underscore" prevents access to the attribute (except by getters), so it kind of emulates a private attribute.